# How to get model objects in the form with rails check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, checkbox, form-helpers

How do i get checkbox values in the form from the database? I want the form to bring the existing sub category name,and when i check the checkbox to select that particular category name and not create a new one.I have tried ryan bate's railscast but was no help to me. The realationship here is `Category has_many SubCategories` and `SubCategory belongs_to Category`.Thank you.

```
 <%= form_for @category ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f| %>
 <%=f.text_field :category_name %>
 <%= f.fields_for :sub_categories do |s| %>
 <% @category.sub_categories.each do |sub|%>
 <%=s.check_box "name",{},sub.id %>  <!--need help here-->
 <%end%> 
 <%end%>
 <%=f.submit "submit"%>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something: You are rendering all the subcategories for the category in your view so what would the purpose of the checkbox be?

Comment: @miked A user will check a subcategory,basically by checking it ,he is selecting it ,so later we should be able to tell what user picked which subcategories

Comment: Right and selecting it does what? Let's say you have CategoryA which already has SubCategoryX, SubCategoryY assigned to it.  You render the form. The form shows up with fields for CategoryA only it's children SubCategoryX and SubCategoryY. Each subcategory has a checkbox -- what attribute is that checkbox setting on the SubCategory?  Are you sure you don't want all possible subcategories displaying for each parent Category form? Whereby checking/unchecking the subcategory would assign/unassign that checked one to the parent?

Comment: yes you are right ,that is what i want,and i have a field in category model called value that will be assigned/unassigned,but i dont know how to set the form to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the exchange in the comments, it appears that you want to use the checkboxes to assign SubCategory objects to a Category object.  If that's the case, you're association should be that a Category has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_categories. Then your form would look something like:

```
<%= form_for @category ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f| %>
 <%=f.text_field :category_name %>
 <% SubCategories.each do |sc| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag :sub_category_ids, sub_category_id, @category.sub_categories.include?(sc), :name => 'category[sub_category_ids][]' -%>
      <%= label_tag :sub_category_ids, sc.name -%>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Which will show a category form and then list all of the sub_categories that can be assigned or unassigned by checking the checkboxes.

You will also need a join table "categories_sub_categories" for this new association and logic (likely in your controller) to handle the actual assignment.

example for your category_controller.rb

```
def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    #use the checked sub_category_ids from the form to find and assign the sub_categories.
    assigned_sub_categories = SubCategory.find(params[:category][:sub_category_ids]) rescue []
    @category.sub_categories = assigned_sub_categories
    if @category.save
      …
    else
      …
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you.what if i had has_many through ,what would i do then?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference as long as your association name stays the same. i.e. has_many :sub_categories, :through=>:whatevers